# Can we add apple passes any browser or any device?

Tags: ios, passbook, wallet

I am adding passes from safari, safari open passbook and store that pass to apple wallet using iCloud (I have login with iCloud in my mac machine).

Can we add apple passes any other device(windows, linux)? Please suggest something.

Comment: I am trying to find out apple document of apple passes dependancies, but i did not get what i want.

Comment: Apple uses certificates to sign the passes, but more info can be found here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/PassKit_Bundle/Chapters/Introduction.html It seems to be that there are some Android apps which are able to open `pkpass` files.

Comment: Thanks Berendschot for replying. It helps me.